# Update tinyint(1)

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to update the status value -tinyint(1)- to activate and deactivate the user. Whenever I try to update I keep getting the message below which set to "Attendant update failed." Any help is appreciate it. Thanks

```
if (empty($errors)) {

// Perform Update

$id = $attendant["id"];
$status = mysql_prep($_POST["status"]);

$query  = "UPDATE attendant SET ";
$query .= "status = '{$status}', ";
$query .= "WHERE id = {$id} ";
$query .= "LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == 1) {
  // Success
  $_SESSION["message"] = "Attendant updated.";
  redirect_to("activate_attendant.php");
} else {
  // Failure
  $_SESSION["message"] = "Attendant update failed.";
}


} 
} else {
// This is probably a GET request

}
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from `'{$status}'`

Comment: Remove the comma in `status = '{$status}',` <= --- The error will show up by doing `$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did, and it works, except that when I update the value, it says "Database query failed" but it updates. Thanks. Do you have any idea what that might be?

Comment: Where is "Database query failed" coming from? It's not in your code.

Comment: It's on my dbConection PHP file. I'll try to debug it. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post an answer below to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the trailing comma in `status = '{$status}',` <=

MySQL would have thrown you an error by doing:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

---

- I would also like to note that your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
  Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.